# Алгоритм проверки является ли число магическим

Tags: c++, алгоритм, сложность, числа

Магическими назовем следующие числа 1, 14, 144. Так на вход программы подается произвольное число и нужно проверить является ли это число магиюеским, то есть число должен состоять только из 1, 14 и 144 чисел. Например 1 14 144 1 1 1 14 14 14 144 1 числи является магическим а 1 14 144 4 1 1 14 14 14 144 1 таким не является. Сложность алгоритма не больше O(n). 
У меня есть частное решение этой задачи и оно заключается в проверке есть ли в числе последовательно расположенных по меньшей мере три 4 (четверок). Если есть то число ме магическое, если не то наоборот. Но мне интересует более общее решение. Каким алгоритмом решить эту задачу или в каких книгах можно найти похожие задачи с решениями.

Comment: правильно ли я понимаю, что на самом то деле число записывается в виде 1141444111414141441 ? или оно именно так с пробелами и записывается?

Comment: вы правильно поняли именно в форме 1141444111414141441

Comment: Спасибо всем. Понятно уже.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Тут линейный жадный алгоритм подойдет: в цикле откусываем от строки максимально длинные возможные куски (1, 14, 144). Если на каком-то шаге откусить не получилось, a строка не пустая, то число не волшебное.

Answer (score 4):

если сложность нужна линейная, то самый простой способ - конечный автомат.

Таблица состояний

```
     1   4    .
S1   S1  S41  err
S41  S1  S42  err
S42  S1  err  err
```

По горизонтали - это входные данные (. - это любой символ). По вертикали - состояния. В центре - новые состояния.

Схематический алгоритм

```
state = s1;
while (!eof()) {
  c = nextchar();
  if (c == '1') {
    state = s1;
  } else if (c == '4') {
    if (state == s1) {
      state = s41;
    } else if (state == s41) {
      state = s42;
    } else if (state == s42) {
      state = err;
      error;
    }
  } else {
    error;
  }
}
ok;
```

код почти на плюсах. state = это enum или может быть даже int c константами. `s1`, `s41`, `s42`, `err` - состояния. error - специальная функция, которая прерывает выполнение и сигнализирует об ошибке. ok - функция, сигнализирующая об успехе. `nextchar` - получает следующий символ.

Answer (score 3):

С CodeForces, да?
Очень много способов решения. От проверки строки регулярным выражением до перебором в лоб.

```
var a = "114144141414414144414";
alert( a.replace(/14{0,2}/g, '') != "");
```

Это число не магическое, так как в определенном месте есть три четверки идущие подряд.
В коде я сначала ищу "1" (единицу) и следом идущую "4" (четверку), которая повторяется от 0 до 2х раз и это действие повторяется до конца строки. Если в итоге строка осталась непустой, то что-то было не так (строка не магическая).

Можно сделать перебором. Вот этот код я отправлял на CodeForces.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    char *a = new char[];
    cin >> a;
    char temp;
    short four = 0;
    bool f = false;

    for (int i=0; i<strlen(a); i++) {
        temp = a[i];
        if (temp == '1') { four = 0; continue; }
        else if (temp == '4') {
            if (++four > 2) { f = true; break; } 
            continue;
        }
        else {
            f = true; break;
        }
    }

    if (f) cout << "NO";
    else cout << "YES";
    return 0;
}
```

(Сам только учу С++). Тут мы посимвольно просматриваем строку и запоминаем предыдущий символ. Прошу второй код строго не судить, так как в отличии от JavaScript (первый способ), C++ я только учу.

Answer (score 1):

Тут были даны частные решения вашей проблемы, давайте поговорим и об *общем* решении.

Итак, у нас есть строка, и необходимо проверить, описывается ли строка некоторой *грамматикой*. В нашем случае грамматика такова:

```
main :== <empty> | main word
word :== '1' | '14' | '144'
```

Наша грамматика является в записанном виде LR-грамматикой, для неё можно написать парсер используя стандартную утилиту yacc (bison):

```
main:
    /* empty */
    | main word
    ;

word:
      '1' { puts("[1]"); }
    | '1' '4' { puts("[14]"); }
    | '1' '4' '4' { puts("[144]"); }
    ;
```

С другой стороны, наша грамматика может быть переписана и как более простая LL-грамматика

```
main :== <empty> | word main
word :== '1' tail
tail :== <empty> | '4' tailtail
tailtail :== <empty> | '4'
```

(Обратите внимание на правую рекурсию вместо левой!) Такая грамматика допускает несложный ручной нисходящий разбор.

Псевдокод:

```
readmain:
    while (!eof(input))
        if (!readword())
            error()

readword:
    if (token != '1')
        return false;
    switch to the next token;
    return readtail

readtail:
    if (token != '4')
        return true;
    switch to the next token;
    return readtailtail;

readtailtail:
    if (token != '4')
        return true;
    switch to the next token;
    return true;
```

Если вас интересует тематика парсеров, есть много литературы, например, Dragon Book.

Comment: @Вардан: пожалуйста! Возможно, пригодится в будущей работе.